# How to recall a function, Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: java, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I'm trying to write code that will work out prime numbers using the sieve of Eratosthenes. I have to include a function that will take in a number and cross of all of the multiples of that number. For testing I set the first number to be 2 and the second as 3. It works for the first number but never for the second(no matter the order of the numbers i.e if I put 3 into the function first). I know there are other completed sieve of Eratosthenes out there but I wanted to try and do it in the way that I thought of first.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Which number would you like to calculate up to?");
    int n = input.nextInt();
    input.close();

    int x = 0;
    int newNumber = 2;
    int numbers[] = new int[n];
    while(newNumber <= n){
        numbers[x] = newNumber;
        x++;
        newNumber++;
    }

    int currentNumber = 2; 
    int finalNumber[] = markOfMultiples(n, numbers, currentNumber);
    for(int y = 0;y < n-1;y++){
        System.out.print(finalNumber[y] + ", ");
    }

    currentNumber = 3; 
    int secondNumber[] = markOfMultiples(n, numbers, currentNumber);
    for(int y = 0;y < n-1;y++){
        System.out.println(secondNumber[y]);
    }

}

public static int[] markOfMultiples(int n, int numbers[], int currentNumber){

    int originalNumber = currentNumber;
    while(currentNumber<n){
        currentNumber = currentNumber + originalNumber;
        int count2 = 0;
        while(currentNumber != numbers[count2] && currentNumber<=n && count2<n){            
            count2++;
        }
        numbers[count2] = 0;
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

The error I'm getting is: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 20

at sieveOfEratosthenes.sieveOfEratosthenes.markOfMultiples(sieveOfEratosthenes.java:46)

at sieveOfEratosthenes.sieveOfEratosthenes.main(sieveOfEratosthenes.java:28)

Line 28 is when I recall the function:`int secondNumber[] = markOfMultiples(n, numbers, currentNumber);`

And line 46 is `while(currentNumber != numbers[count2] && currentNumber<=n && count2<20){`

Any help would be much appreciated. How do I keep on calling the function?

p.s. Please excuse the variable names as I'll be changing them when I get the program working.

Comment: Is this a school assignment? We're doing this at my school.

Comment: Yeah, it's a school assignment

Comment: in Java, you can get the length of an array from e.g. numbers.length; there's no need to pass in the separate length-of-array parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get this approach working, you can do the fix advised by @Thierry to check `count2 < n` first in your while loop and then also surround the line

```
numbers[count2] = 0
```

with an if clause to check count2 is not beyond the end of the index. e.g.

```
if (count2 < n) {
    numbers[count2] = 0;
}
```

Your final challenge is how you call your `markOfMultiples()` function enough times when n gets a bit larger.  It's not a problem with your fundamental approach - you can definitely do it and your approach will work well and have acceptable performance for low-ish numbers (say up to 10000).

## However

I realise this is an assignment and you want to do it your way, but there are a few features of your approach which you might want to consider - maybe after you've got it working.

1. Readability - is it going to be easy for someone looking at (marking) your code to understand what it's doing and verify that it will do the right thing for all values of n?
2. Try not to repeat yourself - for instance consider where you fill your `numbers` array:

   ```
   while(newNumber <= n){
      numbers[x] = newNumber;
      x++;
      newNumber++;
   }
   ```

   Will `x` ever be different to `newNumber`?  Did you need both variables? This sort or repetition occurs elsewhere in your code - the principle to stick to is known as [DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)
3. Is there an easier way to move the index on `originalNumber` places in your `markOfMultiples()` method? (HINT: yes, there is)
4. Do you really need the actual numbers in the numbers[] array? You're going to end up with a lot of zeros and the primes left as integer values if you work out how to call your markOfMultiples repeatedly for high values of n.  Would an array of 1s and 0s (or `true`s and `false`s) be enough if you used the array index to give you the prime number?

Answer (score 1):

You need to test if count2 < n BEFORE access to numbers[count2]:

```
while(count2 < n && currentNumber != numbers[count2] && currentNumber<= n){            
    count2++;
}
```

Comment: @bike3 with the same exception?

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention, its now saying there is a problem with line 50 `numbers[count2] = 0;`